# Cabal project seems to be importing multiple versions of Cabal Library breaking Setup.hs

Tags: haskell, cabal

**Short:**

I have a cabal project that depends on a library built using `cabal sandbox add-source`. This library exports a preprocessor function `BuildInfo -> LocalBuildInfo -> PreProcessor`. When I try to use that preprocessor in the Setup.hs for my main cabal project, I get the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Cabal-1.18.1.3:Distribution.PackageDescription.BuildInfo’
              with ‘BuildInfo’
NB: ‘Cabal-1.18.1.3:Distribution.PackageDescription.BuildInfo’
      is defined in ‘Distribution.PackageDescription’
          in package ‘Cabal-1.18.1.3’
    ‘BuildInfo’
      is defined in ‘Distribution.PackageDescription’
          in package ‘Cabal-1.20.0.1’
```

---

**Less Short:**

I currently have the following directory structure in my cabal sandbox:

```
├── main.cabal
├── Setup.hs
├── Main.hs
├── lib
│   ├── myPP.cabal
│   ├── MyPP.hs
│   └── myPP
│       ├── MyPP.hs
│       ├── myPP.cabal
```

My main package has myPP has a build depends. myPP is a library with MyPP as the exposed module and `Cabal` and `ghc` as dependencies. the MyPP module exports a function

```
myPP :: BuildInfo -> LocalBuildInfo -> PreProcessor
```

I then run

```
cabal sandbox add-source ./lib/*
cabal install myPP
```

In my Setup.hs I have:

```
module Main (main) where
import Distribution.Simple
import Distribution.Simple.PreProcess
import Distribution.Simple.Utils
import Distribution.PackageDescription
import Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo
import MyPP(myPP)
main :: IO ()
main = let hooks = simpleUserHooks
           pp = ("pp",myPP)
       in defaultMainWithHooks hooks {hookedPreProcessors = pp:knownSuffixHandlers}
```

I then attempt to actually `cabal build` only to get the error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Cabal-1.18.1.3:Distribution.PackageDescription.BuildInfo’
              with ‘BuildInfo’
NB: ‘Cabal-1.18.1.3:Distribution.PackageDescription.BuildInfo’
      is defined in ‘Distribution.PackageDescription’
          in package ‘Cabal-1.18.1.3’
    ‘BuildInfo’
      is defined in ‘Distribution.PackageDescription’
          in package ‘Cabal-1.20.0.1’
```

---

**Attempt to diagnose the error:**

My understanding is that when you have a package that depends on both `ghc` and `Cabal`, then you get the version of Cabal that is linked to when `ghc` was built. As a result, the myPP package is built with that old version of cabal. When the custom `Setup.hs` is run by cabal, it imports its version of cabal (which is the one that I have installed). This then causes the error. However, I am hoping that there is a better solution than to just downgrade my version of Cabal....

Answer (score 0):

You won't like the other solution: build ghc from the current HEAD in order to get a newer Cabal (now at 1.21.1.0). Unfortunately, there's just no way to make two different versions of a package coexist in a single build. Downgrading Cabal is probably the least-painful option.